# Best practice of big javascript objects

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

sry for this imprecise topic name.

I am querying a dataset a lot of times so using ajax request would end up in tons of http requests.

For this reason I decided to use the json encode method to store this particular data set in my javascript code.

My php code looks like this: (no json.parse)

```
 echo 'var myDataset = ' . json_encode( $myDataset ) . ';' ;
```

Now here is my question: Which of the following approaches is better?

a)

```
 var myDataset = { '1' : { ... } , ... };

 console.log ( myDataset['1'] );
```

b)

```
 var myDataset = function( id ){ return ({ ... })[id] };

 console.log ( myDataset('1') );
```

Is there any difference in memory or cpu consumption?

Thanks

Jan

Comment: What are the two options doing, specifically?

Comment: The first approach is using a named array the second one is using a anonymous array with a different scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method (a) is the fastest. In some situations using the . syntax can be faster, i.e. `myDataset.a` is faster than `myDataset['a']` which is way faster than `function(a){return myDataset[a];}`. Using functions is very rarely fast. In (b) you do exactly the same as in (a), but you have another function call, and that will add a new closure to the heap, which takes up space and time.

Comment: You can't use the dot syntax with a numeric key. myDataset.1 will fail, it needs to be myDataset[1] or ['1'].

Answer (score 2):

A function only unnecessarily adds extra overhead. If the data is just to be accessed in flavor of object properties, then I'd go for way a).